# Lista de variables en un modelo

Tags: r

Datos:

```
mtcars
```

Hago un modelo:

```
lm(formula = mpg  ~., data = mtcars)
```

Por otro algoritmo obtengo esto:

```
  "disp+hp+drat+wt+qsec" -> lista
```

Si lo meto en el modelo funciona:

```
lm(formula = mpg  ~disp+hp+drat+wt+qsec, data = mtcars)
```

Pero si lo meto así no funciona:

```
lm(formula = mpg  ~lista, data = mtcars)
```

He probado a trasformarlo con todos los as.

```
as.character(lista) -> lista 
as.array(lista) -> lista 
etc
```

pero el modelo no lo coge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes transformar los caracteres a tipo "formula" (objeto del lenguaje) usando `as.formula()` o `formula()`.

Con ayuda de la función `paste()` puedes concatenar los caracteres de la siguiente manera:

```
> as.formula(paste("mpg ~", lista))
# mpg ~ disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec
```

Luego puedes aplicar la función `lm()` a dicho objeto:

```
> lm(as.formula(paste("mpg ~", lista)), data = mtcars)

# Call:
# lm(formula = as.formula(paste("mpg ~", lista)), data = mtcars)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)         disp           hp         drat           wt         qsec  
 #  16.53357      0.00872     -0.02060      2.01577     -4.38546      0.64015
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu caso parece simple, de hecho una rápida respuesta podría ser que uses `as.formula()` para convertir una cadena que representa una fórmula en una formula en sí, el tema es que la cadena debe ser consistente con una formula, por lo que en todo caso deberías hacer algo así:

```
formula_str <- "mpg ~ disp+hp+drat+wt+qsec"

lm(as.formula(formula_str), mtcars)
```

Sin embargo hay un detalle que planteas que es interesante comentar, aunque es un tópico avanzado. En tu caso, quieres combinar una expresión simbólica como `mpg` con una expresión tipo cadena para terminar construyendo la formula. Buscas hacer algo así:

```
mpg ~ convertir_a_expresión_simbolica(cadena)
```

Más allá que existe una función `convertir_a_expresión_simbolica()` en R, hay otro  problema: la función `~` que es quién realmente construye la formula, es totalmente literal con los parámetros que recibe, y en este contexto `convertir_a_expresión_simbolica(cadena)` siempre será una función que convierte a una expresión pero no una expresión en sí.

Podríamos, como alternativa hacer una nueva función de `~` que reciba un símbolo (`mpg`) y una cadena y que entregue siempre una fórmula válida:

```
`%~%` <- function(o, s) {
  as.formula(paste(substitute(o), '~', s))
}

lm(mpg %~% "disp+hp+drat+wt+qsec", mtcars)
```

En el ejemplo `substitute(o)` reemplaza el simbolo `o` por el que se pasó párametro `mpg`, todo se concatena en una cadena y se evalua y retorna la misma como fórmula.